# wordpress redirect https domain to http site

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have a Wordpress site on a domain like http://friend.mysite.com
I want to redirect to this site form a domain with ssl like https://myfriendsdomain.com
I activated ssl and proxy on myfriendsdomain and its also in the browser address bar. The site is shown, but the formatting is broken. looks like css is off or something. I'm an App developer, so I make websites only from time to time.

What can I do, to make this redirection with https work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Cpanel and redirect the domain to a specific location.

Comment: the redirection is already working, just not correctly. Of what help should that unspecific answer be?